# disable keyup jquery when dialog is open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, keyup

I have a Input field on my page. When you type something in there and press enter the page starts a search and shows the results:

```
....
<input id="idSearchFor" type="text" name="SearchFor">
....
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#idSearchFor").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            // start search
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now with a button on my page I open a Dialog for a more detailled search with also an Input:

```
...
<input id="idSearchForDetail" type="text" Name="SearchForData" >
...
$("#idSearchForDetail").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            // start search
    }
});
```

No when I press enter in this Dialog also the keyup-function of the Input in the main page is also activated. How can I disable this keyup-function? Or what can I do so that only the keyup-function of the Dialog is activated.

Comment: try using $("#idSearchForDetail").("on","keyup",function(event) {
for your dialog .May be thi ssolve the issue

Comment: thanks for this Response. But it didn't work.

Comment: try using "on" for both the events .It will surely work I guess

Comment: ok then first I must say the code you gave me has a wrong Syntax I think.
After $('...'). must come a function, or am I wrong. So code like $('...').(...) doesn't work. I tried $('...').keyup("on", function(Event) {... but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, when I found out when I hit enter not the keyup-function reacts but the button click function

```
<input id="idSearchFor" type="text" name="SearchFor">
<input style="border-color: #1D71B8" id="idGo" type="submit" name="Search" value="Los!">

...
<script>
$("#idGo").button().click(function(event) {
    onSubmit();
});
</script>
```

I have a Counter which Counts the opened dialogs. So I now just tell the button.click()-function only to submit my search when no Dialog is open.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#idGo").button().click(function(event) {
        if(dialogcount == 0) {
            onSubmit();
        }
    });
</script>
```